# iPhone web app not reading stylesheet

Tags: iphone, css, ipad, web-applications, iphone-standalone-web-app

I'm currently building a mobile web app, and am using `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` in the header.

The app displays fine in the Safari browser on iPhone and iPad, however once it is saved to the home screen and launched from there, the stylesheet is not being read at all. If I add inline styles to elements they are read, but nothing from my style.css takes effect.

Is this related to the manifest at all, or is there something else I need to change?

Comment: Simply try clearing the cache or refreshing the page...!

Comment: The link is http://m.calebgittins.com.au/. I've tried clearing the cache, deleting the home screen icon and re-adding, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

This Works fine for me in my iPhone, Check out the Screenshots----

**[image: ON SAFARI]**
**[image: AFTER ADDING TO HOME SCREEN]**

Comment: I've cleared the cached an history, turned my phone on and off, and tried re-adding the link to my home screen, but I still can't see any css being using in the app version. Any html changes are reflected but no css. This is happening both on iPhone and iPad.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?